# Laravel php How to return response with certain parameters in JSON format

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.3, response

When i received the message in json format as below:

```
{
  "Details":{
      "Type":"Cash",
      "Payid":"PAY123456",
      "Amount":"9000,00",
      "Status":"Successful",
  }
}
```

I need to return response in the following JSON format with two parameters only (Type & Payid) that received

```
{
  "Details": {
    "Type": "Cash",
    "Payid": "PAY123456"
    }
}
```

Currently in my controller it will return the whole details that received. 
But how do I modified it, so that it will just return the certain parameters.

```
public function returnResponse(Request $request)
{
    $datas= $request->getContent();
    $returnData= json_decode($datas, true);
    return response()->json($returnData);
}
```

Comment: It's not so surprising because you do not modify the content `$datas` before sending it as JSON. Try debugging what exactly is in $datas, modify its content and then send it as JSON.

Comment: hi @marekful, may i know how to modified the content $datas? the content $datas is {
  "Details":{
      "Type":"Cash",
      "Payid":"PAY123456",
      "Amount":"9000,00",
      "Status":"Successful",
  }
}

Comment: There is more than one way of doing it. It mostly depends on how reliable is the received data. You could use `unset($returnData['Details']['Amount']); unset($returnData['Details']['Status']);` after decoding it.

Comment: Assuming it is an instance of stdClass, you can `unset($datas->Details->Amount)`, etc...

Comment: @marekful second argument in `json_decode` means array ;) (And since they are using `json_decode`, we could assume `$datas` is just a string)

Comment: Yep, sorry. So do the same on $returnData instead...

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. But i still not very clear. Can you write out the full code here? Really appreciate if you can write it

Comment: Take a look: [https://eval.in/863336](https://eval.in/863336).

Comment: Oh, and that's not proper json, really. That extra comma (`,`) makes it invalid (tested it at [https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/))

Comment: ok. Thanks @FirstOne. Another is in return response, if i want to add a new parameter to details "confirmation": "00". How should i add it in returnData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
public function returnResponse(Request $request){
    $datas = $request->getContent();
    $parsedJson = json_decode($datas, true);
    $returnData = array('Details' => array(
        'Type' => $parsedJson['Details']['Payid'],
        'Payid' => $parsedJson['Details']['Payid'],
        'Confirmation' => 0 // do the same in this line if you want to add more
    ));
    return response()->json($returnData);
}
```

This code assumes you'll always have 'Type' and 'Payid' inside 'Details'.

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [Details] => Array
        (
            [Type] => PAY123456
            [Payid] => PAY123456
            [Confirmation] => 0
        )

)
```

---

Note, if you just want to add `Confirmation` to the original array, you can use:

```
$returnData['Details']['Confirmation'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide the parameter that you don't want your customer or user to see go to the Model file and

```
protected $hidden=[
// here you will type the property name like
"update_at",
]
```